# Error when building (Checking validity of types) using Prisma

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, prisma

node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.d.ts:1161:35 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

`1161 |     select: infer S extends object; |                                   ^ 1162 | } & Record<string, unknown> | { 1163 |     include: infer I extends object;`

everything is normal, but when I want to build, there is an error in library.d.ts in the node modules @prisma/client

Comment: run `prisma generate` again

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: done bro, its my typescript version, you just need to npm update

Answer (score 0):

updating node version to 18.18.2 resolved it.

I used nvm